# Save file from Richtextbox using Invoke

Tags: c#, richtextbox, backgroundworker, invoke

I am having a `RichTextbox` and I am trying to save file using

```
public bool SaveNote(string path)
{
    try
    {
        _rtbContent.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It was working fine until I started working with background worker thread. Now this method is being called from background worker and now I am receiving an error as

```
Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'rtbContent' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

I think we have to invoke it using `_rtbContent.Invoke` but failing to get the syntax correct. What I tried was

```
if(_rtbContent.InvokeRequired)
    _rtbContent.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(_rtbContent.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)));
```

Here I am getting `Method name expected` compilation error on `_rtbContent.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)`.

I am not very comfortable in using these threads but has recently started working on them. Can anyone help me on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a callback:

```
delegate void SaveNoteCallback(string path);

public void SaveNote(string path)
{
    if(_rtbContent.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SaveNoteCallback d = new SaveNoteCallback(SaveNote);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] {path});
    }
    else 
    {
        _rtbContent.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got another interesting solution and would like to post that.

```
public void SaveNote(string path)
{
    if(_rtbContent.InvokeRequired)
    {
        _rtbContent.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate{_rtbContent.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText}));

        //Below is also same as above
        //_rtbContent.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(()=>_rtbContent.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)));
    }
    else 
    {
        _rtbContent.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);    
    }
}
```

I think it is much clean solution. Hope it helps.